# Question on generic A-packet

Tags: algebraic-groups, automorphic-forms

Let $G$ be a classical group and $\phi$ be a generic $A$-parameter of $G$.

I am wondering whether each automorphic representations in the $A$-packet associated to $\phi$ are locally generic at almost all places.

I am also wondering whether there is a globally generic automorphic representation in the $A$-packet associated to $\phi$.